# Trying to mock Expo's AsyncStorage module using Jest

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, asyncstorage

I'm currently trying to write Jest tests for my React Native application, testing my fetch commands as such:

```
const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("id");
let response = await fetch('http://192.168.0.12:3000/auth/login', {
   method: 'GET',
   headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
   }
});
let res = await response.json();
...rest of code
```

But I can't seem to find any mocking solutions for Async Storage one version before (ie. **WITHIN React Native, NOT the current @react-native-community/async-storage**. Currently, I've tried fully mocking the module like so, and checking whether the getItem() method is ever called:

```
test('tests Login', () => {
jest.mock('react-native', () => {
  AsyncStorage: {        
    getItem: jest.fn(() => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{         
            resolve("cool");
        });
    })
}
});

expect(AsyncStorage.getItem).toBeCalled();
});
```

But this currently returns the following error:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalled()

Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls: 0
```

And when I change it to this (which I don't think is the right way):

```
expect(AsyncStorage.getItem()).toBeCalled()
```

it returns a Promise that doesn't resolve:

```
expect(received).toBeCalled()
Received has type: object
Received has value: {"_40": 0, "_55":undefined, "_65": 1, "_72": null}
```

My question is, **how can I mock the older version of AsyncStorage to check whether the function has been called, or have the mock return a constant value so the test can execute the rest of the method**? Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. I have tried the various solutions suggested on SO, but all have returned the same errors. The current software I am using is: 
React Native (Expo SDK 37.0.0),
Jest,
React-test-renderer

Comment: `expect(AsyncStorage.getItem())` is wrong because you're asserting a function to be called, not the value it returns, it should be `expect(AsyncStorage.getItem)`. `jest.mock` should happen before the module is imported. You can't have it inside `test`. Either move `jest.mock` to top level, or move imports that depend on AsyncStorage inside `test`.

Comment: Thanks! I tried moving my imports inside test() but got another error (cannot find AsyncStorage), will try moving it into my setupTests.js file and see what happens